# FTP and EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've got my EC2 instance up and running and installed vsftpd with yum install vsftpd. Now I've started the service.

But unfortunately it seems like the guides end at this point.

How do I actually use my ftp client to log into the ftp server?

What do I input server url, username, password, and all that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use SFTP and FileZilla, just check this out - http://y2u.be/e9BDvg42-JI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need the same credentials you use to log into a command line on the EC2 instance - the host name or IP address, plus the username (usually root) and the SSH keypair that you used when you created the instance.

Then you'll be able to connect with any client that supports SFTP (e.g. CyberDuck on Mac, WinSCP on Windows)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is the host name the public DNS name I get from elasticfox? I can't tell what I use to connect with SSH because I just connect through elasticfox. I'm getting: 
Error:Connection timed out
Error:Could not connect to server

when I try to connect with the public dns. thanks.

Comment: Yes, the host name is the public DNS name from ElasticFox.  The SSH key you need is the file that ElasticFox asks for when you click the "Connect to Instance" button.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the right ports in the security group to enable FTP, not only port 21 but also ports required by FTP passive mode. The sample configuration is described below.

Required AWS Security Group changes:

- open port 21
- open port range 12000-12100

Add the following lines to the /etc/vsftpd.conf file:

```
pasv_min_port=12000
pasv_max_port=12100
```

Restart vsftpd server:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

You may also consider opening the above ports in your Security Group
for a very specific source IP address/range, then you will be able to
connect to your EC2 instance only from your machine what is a little
bit safer. However, and as replied by Gareth, a more secure setup is
using SFTP, which goes over SSH. I recommend you also to take a look
at the BitNami wiki articles describing how to connect to [Linux](http://wiki.bitnami.org/cloud/how_to_connect_to_your_amazon_instance) or
[Windows](http://wiki.bitnami.org/cloud/How_to_connect_to_your_Windows_AMI%3f) instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I had credentials from EHCP but had to open the passive ports and mod the config file.  You answer works for amazon AWS with EHCP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect with FTP (not SFTP) just open port 21 from your Amazon instance.

From the FTP client, put your username/password and from connection type select use port (Cute Ftp). For other FTP client there should be something similar.

In this way you don't need to open any other ports or you don't need any extra credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect with ftp instead of sftp then you need to install webmin first.

Installing webmin:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install webmin
```

If there is no repository than follow these steps first:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.600_all.deb
```

Run this command:

```
dpkg --install webmin_1.600_all.deb

apt-get install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python
```

Then configure ftp.

After configuring you can use filezilla, aceftp or some other ftp program. But this will work in passive mode.